# Share my email in chat, user to user

Tags: feature-request, chat

Many times people share their email to another user in the chat room, for personal purposes and even for community purposes, for instance: translation coordination (all this happens at least in Stack Overflow en Español chat room).

I would like to have a option that allow me to send my email address to a specific user, something like <kbd>Share email with...</kbd>.

This would be useful in order to prevent my email being recorded in the room or published via RSS.

It would be a private way to share my real private email address that Stack Overflow already has in my profile.

> It is different of the duplicate-candidate question because: I just want send my email, not private messages. I understand that private messages is never going to be implemented here and that is the main reason why I am asking this feature: to send just the email without need to send a private message that Stack Overflow already knows.

Comment: @rene I hope to have clarified the difference

Comment: right, but the answer is very ugly... _Find an old post authored by the intended recipient and comment_ really? should work but... i don´t know... very ugly. i still preferring a button. anyway thank you for this information.

Comment: Well, that is no longer the highest voted answer ...and I choose that duplicate because of the [tag:status-declined] tag on it.

Comment: If you want to share an email in chat, ping a moderator first so that they're on hand when you do so and can remove the message and its history.